# Can reinforcement learning algorithms be applied to computer vision problems?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, computer-vision, applications, reference-request

Can reinforcement learning algorithms be applied to computer vision problems? If yes, what are some examples of these applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to apply reinforcement learning in computer vision problems. This mainly employs the principle of "applying the algorithm -> evaluating the outcome -> adopting the best outcome".

The following are a couple of examples that use reinforcement learning in computer vision.

- [CAD2RL: Real Single-Image Flight Without a Single
  Real Image](https://storage.googleapis.com/rss2017-papers/13.pdf).
- [End-to-End Training of Deep Visuomotor
  Policies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.00702)